# sql JOIN is exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having some problems with this query below. I have all my users in a table named `ItemInstances` and all my data for the users in tables named `ItemPropertyValuesInt`, `ItemPropertyValuesBool` etc.

This query works fine until I add the `IsBanned` query. Not all users have an entry in this table so only 5 users are returned instead of 300. My understanding was that a `LEFT JOIN` would be the solution but maybe I've misunderstood how to write this in this query.

Any additional optimisation tips for this query would also be welcome as the database is HUGE

```
SELECT ItemInstances.Id,
    Relics.PropertyValue AS Hugo_Relics,
    AllianceID.PropertyValue AS Hugo_AllianceID,
    Faction.PropertyValue AS Hugo_Faction,
    LevelXP.PropertyValue AS Hugo_Level,
    WeeklyRelics.PropertyValue AS Hugo_WeeklyRelics,
    UserName.PropertyValue AS Hugo_UserName,
    ItemInstances.CreatorId,
    IsBanned.PropertyValue
FROM dbo.ItemInstances
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ItemPropertyValuesInt Faction
    ON Faction.RecordId = ItemInstances.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ItemPropertyValuesInt LevelXP
    ON LevelXP.RecordId = ItemInstances.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ItemPropertyValuesInt Relics
    ON ItemInstances.Id = Relics.RecordId
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ItemPropertyValuesInt AllianceID
    ON ItemInstances.Id = AllianceID.RecordId
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ItemPropertyValuesInt WeeklyRelics
    ON WeeklyRelics.RecordId = ItemInstances.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ItemPropertyValuesString UserName
    ON UserName.RecordId = ItemInstances.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ItemPropertyValuesBool IsBanned
    ON IsBanned.RecordId = ItemInstances.Id
WHERE Relics.PropertyId = 541
    AND AllianceID.PropertyId = 504
    AND Faction.PropertyId = 520
    AND LevelXP.PropertyId = 529
    AND WeeklyRelics.PropertyId = 730
    AND UserName.PropertyId = 554
    AND IsBanned.PropertyId = 728
ORDER BY Hugo_Relics DESC
```

Comment: From your description only your last join needs to be an outer join. Also, if you do `AND IsBanned.PropertyId = 728` then that's going to filter out any rows that didn't have a match in IsBanned.

Comment: All the `where` conditions should be moved to appropriate `on` clauses, if you intend to use `left outer join`.  Putting them in the `where` clauses turns the outer joins to inner joins, because `NULL` values fail the comparisons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there aren't going to be records that matched in the left joined table, you need to account for that in any WHERE clause conditions.  For example:

```
AND (IsBanned.PropertyId = 728 OR IsBanned.PropertyId IS NULL)
```

Comment: Or simply add `IsBanned.PropertyId = 728` to the `LEFT JOIN` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are left joining you are also selecting on

`AND IsBanned.PropertyId = 728`

The users that are not in the Banned Table have a isBanned.PropertyId of null

So you aren't selecting them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not perfectly clear on your query's intent, but I have a feeling this is how it should be formatted.

```
FROM dbo.ItemInstances
LEFT JOIN dbo.ItemPropertyValuesInt Faction
    ON  Faction.RecordId = ItemInstances.Id
    AND Faction.PropertyId = 520
LEFT JOIN dbo.ItemPropertyValuesInt LevelXP
    ON  LevelXP.RecordId = ItemInstances.Id
    AND LevelXP.PropertyId = 529
LEFT JOIN dbo.ItemPropertyValuesInt Relics
    ON  Relics.RecordId = ItemInstances.Id
    AND Relics.PropertyId = 541
LEFT JOIN dbo.ItemPropertyValuesInt AllianceID
    ON  AllianceID.RecordId = ItemInstances.Id
    AND AllianceID.PropertyId = 504
LEFT JOIN dbo.ItemPropertyValuesInt WeeklyRelics
    ON  WeeklyRelics.RecordId = ItemInstances.Id
    AND WeeklyRelics.PropertyId = 730
LEFT JOIN dbo.ItemPropertyValuesString UserName
    ON  UserName.RecordId = ItemInstances.Id
    AND UserName.PropertyId = 554
LEFT JOIN dbo.ItemPropertyValuesBool IsBanned
    ON  IsBanned.RecordId = ItemInstances.Id
    AND IsBanned.PropertyId = 728
WHERE ItemInstances.Id = ?
```

Gordon Linoff's comment explains it pretty well.

```
LEFT JOIN b ON b.id = a.id AND b.value = x
--All records from [a] retained
--Only records from [b] where b.value = x LEFT JOIN'd to [a]
```

is very different from

```
LEFT JOIN b ON b.id = a.id WHERE b.value = x
--Only records from [a] and [b] where [b].value = x are retained
```